# find common elements in >2 files

Tags: awk, compare

I have three files as shown below

file1.txt

```
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 0 1
"abc" 0 1
"abd" 1 1 
"xxx" 0 0
```

file2.txt

```
"xyz" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 1
"xxx" 0 0
"abc" 1 1
```

file3.txt

```
"xyx" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 1 0
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1
```

I want to find the similar elements in all the three files based on first two columns. To find similar elements in two files i have used something like

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]++;next}a[$1,$2]' file1.txt file2.txt
```

But, how can we find similar elements in all the files, when the input files are more than 2?
Can anyone help?

With the current awk solution, the output ignores the duplicate key columns and gives the output as

```
"xxx" 0 0
```

If we assume the output comes from file1.txt, the expected output is:

```
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 0 1
"xxx" 0 0
```

i.e it should get the rows with duplicate key columns as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following solution generalized for **N** files. It saves data of first file in a hash with value of `1`, and for each hit from next files that value is incremented. At the end I compare if the value of each key it's the same as the number of files processed and print only those that match.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { arr[$1,$2] = 1; next }
    { if ( arr[$1,$2] ) { arr[$1,$2]++ } }
    END { 
        for ( key in arr ) {
            if ( arr[key] != ARGC - 1 ) { continue }
            split( key, key_arr, SUBSEP )
            printf "%s %s\n", key_arr[1], key_arr[2] 
        } 
    }
' file{1..3}
```

It yields:

```
"xxx" 0
"aba" 0
```

---

**EDIT** to add a version that prints the whole line (see comments). I've added another array with same key where I save the line, and also use it in the `printf` function. I've left old code commented.

```
awk '
    ##FNR == NR { arr[$1,$2] = 1; next }
    FNR == NR { arr[$1,$2] = 1; line[$1,$2] = $0; next }
    { if ( arr[$1,$2] ) { arr[$1,$2]++ } }
    END { 
        for ( key in arr ) {
            if ( arr[key] != ARGC - 1 ) { continue }
            ##split( key, key_arr, SUBSEP )
            ##printf "%s %s\n", key_arr[1], key_arr[2] 
            printf "%s\n", line[ key ] 
        } 
    }
' file{1..3}
```

---

**NEW EDIT** (see comments) to add a version that handles multiple lines with same key. Basically I join all entries instead saving only one, changing `line[$1,$2] = $0` with `line[$1,$2] = line[$1,$2] ( line[$1,$2] ? SUBSEP : "" ) $0`. At the time of printing I do the reverse splitting with the separator (`SUBSEP` variable) and print each entry.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { 
        arr[$1,$2] = 1
        line[$1,$2] = line[$1,$2] ( line[$1,$2] ? SUBSEP : "" ) $0
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 { delete found }
    { if ( arr[$1,$2] && ! found[$1,$2] ) { arr[$1,$2]++; found[$1,$2] = 1 } }
    END { 
        num_files = ARGC -1 
        for ( key in arr ) {
            if ( arr[key] < num_files ) { continue }
            split( line[ key ], line_arr, SUBSEP )
            for ( i = 1; i <= length( line_arr ); i++ ) { 
                printf "%s\n", line_arr[ i ]
            } 
        } 
    }
' file{1..3}
```

With new data edited in question, it yields:

```
"xxx" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 0 1
```

Comment: @user1779730: Use `find` to select all files that you want to process, like: `awk '...' $(find /your/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*your_pattern*' -print)` or whatever the selection you need.

Comment: @user1779730: I don't understand what do you mean. It's not an `awk` issue the decision of what files you want to process. You want determine automatically the number of files but, based in what?

Comment: the code should run on whatever number of files of pattern *.txt present in the directory

Comment: Hi, the above code outputs only the two key columns. Could it be modified to get all the columns from one of the files if the key columns are same? i.e in the above example the output should be "xxx"    0  0 and "aba"  0  0.

Comment: thanks it worked as expected. And i have doubt that, will the same code works fine if there are unequal number of columns in each file?

Comment: @user1779730: Yes. It should work, supposing that common lines are equal in all files.

Comment: I have modified my initial question i.e. the rest of the columns other than key columns can be different in the remaining files. And the output could be from any of those files i.e. the output could be "xxx" 0 0, "aba" 0 0 or "xxx" 0 0, "aba" 0 0 0 0 or "xxx" 0 0 0 1 , "aba" 0 0. I hope the above code does the same thing.

Comment: @user1779730: I meant that lines with same key (first two fields) could have more fields with different values and then I wouldn't know which of them to choose. But as you point out in last comment, I understand that it doesn't mind, so I hope there will be no problem with unequal number of columns.

Comment: @user1779730: Yes. The code will do the same thing, but for common lines will print the first appearance, so those lines of first file.

Comment: @user1779730: Sorry. I don't understand all your output options and in what way current script doesn't work. Try to edit your question and add (1) the output you expect and (2) how this script doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I have tried the updated answer with 3 original files. There are still some issues with the output.The output has rows in which the key columns are present in only two files but absent in the third.The output should contain only those rows(from any of the input files) where the key columns are present in all the files.

Comment: @user1779730: Yes. I know what you mean. I've updated the last edit to fix it. I use an additional array `found` to only increment each key once for each file. I hope it works now.

Comment: Hi one small issue with the code. At the end there is printf "%s\n" in the code. I am using this code in a python module and the string format is causing problems for me. %s is treated as a string in python instead of an awk string. Is there any alternative to replace the '%s' with any other character in the printf statement?

Comment: @user1779730: Yes. Use a normal `print` instead: `print line_arr[ i ]`

Comment: Is there a way to define "x" the number of files in which the key columns should be common.

Answer (score 1):

This python script will list out the common lines among all files :

```
import sys
i,l = 0,[]
for files in sys.argv[1:]:
  l.append(set())
  for line in open(files): l[i].add(" ".join(line.split()[0:2]))
  i+=1
commonFields =  reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1 & s2, l)
for files in sys.argv[1:]:
  print "Common lines in ",files
  for line in open(files):
    for fields in commonFields:
      if fields in line:
        print line,
        break
```

Usage : python script.py file1 file2 file3 ...

Comment: thanks for the code. it would be more helpful for me if it is an awk script

Answer (score 1):

For three files, all you need is:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

The `FNR==NR` block returns true for only the first file in the arguments list. The `next` statement in this block forces a skip over the remained of the code. Therefore, `($1,$2) in a` is performed for all files in the arguments list excluding the first one. To process more files in the way you have, all you need to do is list them.

---

If you need more powerful globbing on the command line, use `extglob`. You can turn it on with `shopt -s extglob`, and turn it off with `shopt -u extglob`. For example:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file1.txt !(file1.txt)
```

---

If you have hard to find files, use `find`. For example:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file1.txt $(find /path/to/files -type f -name "*[23].txt")
```

---

I assume you're looking for a glob range for 'N' files. For example:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file1.txt file{2,3}.txt
```

Comment: thanks. here i have mentioned 3 files, but in general i would have n files. How can we generalize it to n files

Comment: @user1779730: Please see the comment above. HTH.

Comment: @user1779730: Exactly what doesn't work? I have tested the code, but you will need to be more specific if your require an output different to what you describe in your question.