# find common elements in N files

Tags: python, awk

I have many .txt files (N) that contain the names of several genes in the first column. The names are sorted and no redundant in the single files. I'm looking for a script that lists the names of the genes that are common in all the N files and write them in a new txt file. Or ,if is possible, an output with the common genes presents in the N-1, N-2, N-..., files. I found a python possible solution in this previous post [find common elements in >2 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935918/find-common-elements-in-2-files) but I'm not sure that is correct for my problem.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: show a short example of your code with several small sample files.  What are your results?  How are they wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f1 file_whatever > b
for f in file*; do
     cut -f1 f > a
     comm -12 a b > c; mv c b
done
cat b
```

unfit question. only answering because you are looking for genes