# Find common elements in a particular column >2 files and print the corresponding lines from each

Tags: python, unix, awk

my question is an extension of one asked a long time ago. The question was to find common elements in >2 files in linux, upon matching entries in particular columns.

The question was (I am referring to this post: [find common elements in >2 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935918/find-common-elements-in-2-files) )

I have three files as shown below

**file1.txt**

```
"aba" 0 0 1
"abc" 0 1
"abd" 1 1 
"xxx" 0 0
```

**file2.txt**

```
"xyz" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 1
"xxx" 0 0
"abc" 1 1
```

**file3.txt**

```
"xyx" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1
```

I want to find the similar elements in all the three files based on first two columns.

Now, I want not only to find the similar elements from all the files, but also to print the corresponding lines from all the files. Note that none of my files are sorted.

Note: I am looking to match elements in column 1 only from all files and print the corresponding lines from the files sequentially.

So, in this example my desired output would be:

```
"xxx" 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
"aba" 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
"abc" 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

where it is printing the matching elemnts ($1) from files 1-3 sequentially.

One user had provided the following solution to this:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { 
        arr[$1,$2] = 1
        line[$1,$2] = line[$1,$2] ( line[$1,$2] ? SUBSEP : "" ) $0
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 { delete found }
    { if ( arr[$1,$2] && ! found[$1,$2] ) { arr[$1,$2]++; found[$1,$2] = 1 } }
    END { 
        num_files = ARGC -1 
        for ( key in arr ) {
            if ( arr[key] < num_files ) { continue }
            split( line[ key ], line_arr, SUBSEP )
            for ( i = 1; i <= length( line_arr ); i++ ) { 
                printf "%s\n", line_arr[ i ]
            } 
        } 
    }
' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

However, this matches the first 2 columns and only prints the entire line from the file that appears first in the list (here file1.txt)

The output this gives is:

```
"xxx" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 
"aba" 0 0 1
```

Is there a way to modify this script so that it prints the matching lines from all files. I need the lines to be displayed side by side, in the format mentioned above. My file is tab-delimited, so would like the output to be tab-delimited as well. Another important point is that the files all contain the same no of columns but differing no of rows.

Comment: Is aba meant to appear twice in the expected result?

Comment: Actually in my file the elemens are unique. In this example aba is present twice, so might create a confusion. If you want you can assume that I am comparing the first two columns, and the elements in column 1 are all unique. thank you. In the second column however, there are duplicates, but the first column takes precedence.

Comment: Moreover, I think there is no need to compare elements in column 2. Since in my files, column 1 values are all unique, I can just match them among all files, and display the lines from each file containing the common elements.

Comment: So shouldn't abc appear also?

Comment: Yes, abc should appear if I match only first column. In the example given it is matching the first two columns, so abc does not appear. I am interested in matching column 1. I'll make the necessary edits in the original post.

Comment: Is the order of the output lines important? What determines the order?

Comment: No the order of the output is not important. In the example given the order is determined by the file that it the first in the list. But it doesn't matter here.

Comment: @David: *Actually in my file the elemens are unique.* Please correct your example files and example output so they reflect unique elements. Otherwise the answers you get will not be correct...

Comment: I have modified my input files to avoid confusion.

Comment: @David: Please also update the example output based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ head file?.txt
==> file1.txt <==
"aba" 0 0 1
"abc" 0 1
"abd" 1 1 
"xxx" 0 0

==> file2.txt <==
"xyz" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 1
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1

==> file3.txt <==
"xyx" 0 0
"aba" 0 1 0
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1
```

Assuming that the appearance `"aba"` twice in the files is a typo (from the comments) you can do this:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$1]++
     s=""
     for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s=s OFS $i
     seen[$1]= seen[$1] s}
     END{for (e in seen) if (cnt[e]>1) print e, seen[e]}' file?.txt
```

Prints:

```
"aba"  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
"abc"  0 1 1 1 1 1
"xxx"  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

---

From Comments.

Given:

```
$ head file{1..3}.txt
==> file1.txt <==
"aba" 0 0 1
"abc" 0 1
"abd" 1 1 
"xxx" 0 0

==> file2.txt <==
"xyz" 0 0
"aba" 0 0 0 1
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1

==> file3.txt <==
"xyx" 0 0
"xxx" 0 0 0 1
"abc" 1 1
```

(Note `"aba"` eliminated in file 3...)

You can use this awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {fcnt++} 
    {cnt[$1]++
    s=""
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s=s OFS $i
    seen[$1]= seen[$1] s}
    END{for (e in seen) if (cnt[e]==fcnt) print e, seen[e]}' file{1..3}.txt
```

Prints:

```
"abc"  0 1 1 1 1 1
"xxx"  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. However, when running your awk script, I am getting as output:

0 1 0 1 0,

1 1 1 1 1,

0 0 0 1 0 0 0
The commas are for line separators.For some reason I cannot format the comment section in the code format

Comment: Are your files from Windows?

Comment: I am working on a windows machine, using Linux based server through MobaXterm

Comment: The extra line feeds are likely from your environment. They are not coming from the awk script.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Somehow each of my lines had an invsible ^M attached to the end character, which was causing the problem.

Comment: [HERE](https://riptutorial.com/awk/example/28963/modifying-rows-on-the-fly--e-g--to-fix-windows-line-endings-) is a method to remove extra line terminators in awk. Can't test because no Windows machines here.

Comment: Could you modify the script so that it only prints the lines IFF n element is found in all the files? Your script works great, but it prints the lines from the files even if the element matches in only 2 files. In the example you worked out, say if "abc" was not present in file3.txt, the output should not contain abc at all. Here, it will still print abc lines from file1 and file2.

Comment: @David I haven't read your question since you already have an accepted answer but it sounds like you accepted an answer that doesn't do what you want, thereby discouraging anyone else from posting an answer that might do what you want, and are now hoping that the one person who posted this answer will have the time/ability to modify it to do what you want. For future questions you may want to wait until you get 1 or more answers that do exactly what you want before accepting one of them.

Comment: @EdMorton: To be fair -- it does exactly what he asked in the question. If he wants that additional functionality, the examples and questions need to say that.

Comment: @dawg ah, so its a [Chameleon Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and they should ask a new followup question.

Comment: @EdMorton: exactly

Comment: @David: To the extent I understand what you are looking for, I made that modification.